# Opencart registration page State/region dropdown doesn't load

Tags: themes, opencart

I'm using opencart 1.5.1 with the theme *crista_blue* which according to their website is compatible with opencart 1.5.1.

A very similar question was asked here: [-SOLVED- Opencart can't load Region / State dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801126/solved-opencart-cant-load-region-state-dropdown) but the answer there says "*In the controller `catalog/controller/account/register.php` there is no such an action called `zone` - therefore the server returns a 404 response and no zones are loaded.*"

My `enroll.php` file does have a `zone` action in it. Which makes me think the problem is of a different nature.

Two other people built this site and are no longer around to maintain it. It seems at first they used the default `register.tpl`/`register.php` for the account creation but then decided to change the welcome page where the "register" link takes you to `enroll.php`/`enroll.tpl`.

This is the website https://www.mybaysix.com/. If you click the Register link at the bottom you are brought to a form where the *Region* / *State* dropdown appears but is empty. If you hit continue the page displays the error messages for the required fields, and the *Region* / *State* dropdown box is now loaded with options.

Here is the `enroll.tpl` file:

```html
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
<div class="breadcrumb">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href'];    ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
<?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
<div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<p><?php echo $text_buyer_information; ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="register">


<!-- Company info -->
<h2><?php echo $text_your_address; ?> </h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_company) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_company; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_federal_tax; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="federal_tax" value="<?php echo $federal_tax; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_federal_tax) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_federal_tax; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_dba; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="dba" value="<?php echo $dba; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_dba) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_dba; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_state_resale; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="state_resale" value="<?php echo $state_resale; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_state_resale) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_state_resale; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $entry_store_website; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="store_website" value="<?php echo $store_website; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_city; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_city) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_city; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_postcode) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_postcode; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
      <td><select name="country_id" onchange="$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=' + this.value + '&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');">
          <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
          <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
          <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
      <td><select name="zone_id">
        </select>
        <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<h2><?php echo $text_your_password; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirm; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>



<h2><?php echo $text_buyer_information; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_firstname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_firstname) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_firstname; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_lastname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_lastname) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_lastname; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_telephone) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_telephone; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_fax; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h2><?php echo $text_owner_information; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_owner_fname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="owner_fname" value="<?php echo $owner_fname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_owner_lname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="owner_lname" value="<?php echo $owner_lname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_owner_phone; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="owner_phone" value="<?php echo $owner_phone; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_owner_fax; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="owner_fax" value="<?php echo $owner_fax; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_owner_email; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="owner_email" value="<?php echo $owner_email; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h2><?php echo $text_manager_information; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_manager_fname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manager_fname" value="<?php echo $manager_fname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_manager_lname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manager_lname" value="<?php echo $manager_lname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_manager_phone; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manager_phone" value="<?php echo $manager_phone; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_manager_fax; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manager_fax" value="<?php echo $manager_fax; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_manager_email; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manager_email" value="<?php echo $manager_email; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h2><?php echo $text_other_information; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_other_fname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="other_fname" value="<?php echo $other_fname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_other_lname; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="other_lname" value="<?php echo $other_lname; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_other_phone; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="other_phone" value="<?php echo $other_phone; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_other_fax; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="other_fax" value="<?php echo $other_fax; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_other_email; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="other_email" value="<?php echo $other_email; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<h2><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></h2>
<div class="content">
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_newsletter; ?></td>
      <td><?php if ($newsletter == 1) { ?>
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" />
        <?php echo $text_no; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" />
        <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
        <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" checked="checked" />
        <?php echo $text_no; ?>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>
    <?php if ($agree) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
    <?php } ?>
    <a onclick="$('#register').submit();" class="button"><span><?php echo $button_continue; ?></span></a></div>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="right"><a onclick="$('#register').submit();" class="button"><span><?php echo $button_continue; ?></span></a></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</form>
<?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=<?php echo $country_id; ?>&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
width: 560,
height: 560,
autoDimensions: false
});
//--></script>  
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

This is the `zone` function at the bottom of `enroll.php`:

```php
public function zone() {
    $output = '<option value="">' . $this->language->get('text_select') . '</option>';

    $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

    $results = $this->model_localisation_zone->getZonesByCountryId($this->request->get['country_id']);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $result['zone_id'] . '"';

        if (isset($this->request->get['zone_id']) && ($this->request->get['zone_id'] == $result['zone_id'])) {
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        }

        $output .= '>' . $result['name'] . '</option>';
    } 

    if (!$results) {
        $output .= '<option value="0">' . $this->language->get('text_none') . '</option>';
    }

    $this->response->setOutput($output);
}
```

I've never used opencart before so if there is any more information that would help figure out the problem just ask.

EDIT: I attempted shadyyx's first answer below and this was the result.

I changed the `.load` to `('index.php?route=account/enroll/zone&country_id=<?php echo $country_id; ?>&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');`

I also tried with the full path `/catalog/controller/account/enroll/`. The dropdown still didn't populate. When I hit continue with nothing filled out an error appears at the top `Notice: Undefined index: zone_id in /home/mybaysix/public_html/catalog/controller/account/enroll.php on line 551`

Line 551 of `enroll.php` is `if ($this->request->post['zone_id'] == '') { $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone'); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [-SOLVED- Opencart can't load Region / State dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801126/solved-opencart-cant-load-region-state-dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

First, welcome to Stack OverFlow!

Your `enroll.php` maybe does have the `zone()` function, but in Your HTML's JavaScript, You are calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=<?php echo $country_id; ?>&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');
//--></script>
```

Thus You are trying to load `/catalog/controller/account/register.php::zone()`...

Instead You should be calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=<DIRECTORY>/enroll/zone&country_id=<?php echo $country_id; ?>&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');
//--></script>
```

Switch the `<DIRECTORY>` value with the correct one...

---

**EDIT**:

1. use only `account/enroll/zone`, not the full path
2. change the condition on that line `551` from

   `if ($this->request->post['zone_id'] == '')`

   to

   `if ($this->request->get['zone_id'] == '')` (mind switching from `post` -> `get`).

   ---

**EDIT 2:**

I guess the dev team messed many things up when *reimplementing the registration* form... The `$('#register').submit();` is OK as Your `<form ...>` has `id="register"`. Try again this change: from

```
if ($this->request->get['zone_id'] == '')
```

to

```
if (isset($this->request->get['zone_id'] == ''))
```

Now the `Notice: Undefined index: zone_id` error shouldn't occur.

Comment: Pretty sure this is correct (and it looks like a compatibility issue as if I recall correctly the zone method moved in 1.5.X from one place to another)

Comment: I updated my post above to say what occurred when I made that change.

Comment: No change with those changes. The same error occurs as before `Notice: Undefined index: zone_id in /home/mybaysix/public_html/catalog/controller/account/enroll.php on line 551`

I just noticed the continue button on the form in `enroll.tpl` is written like:

        `<a onclick="$('#register').submit();" class="button">`

Could that be why the dropdown loads correctly after hitting continue?
We have a form that uses `register.php`/`register.tpl` which loads the dropdown correctly, but doesn't submit the information correctly (multiple people worked on this site before I inherited it).

Comment: `if (isset($this->request->get['zone_id'] == '')) {
        $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
     }`

Throws the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ',' or ')' in controller/account/enroll.php on line 551 `

I appreciate all the help you've given me, but we decided instead of bandaging this code up we are going to create a new form as the current one has other problems besides this one. Would accepting this answer be against the rules? It didn't really fix the problem but did help point me in the direction we want to go.